# better implementaion of a global Zend_Log instance?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Is there a better way to have a globally accessible Zend_Log object?

In Bootstrap.php I'm doing:

```
protected function _initLogging()
{
    $logger = new Zend_Log();
    $writer = new Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../app.log');
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    Zend_Registry::set('log', $logger);
}
```

Then throughout the application I'll use:

```
Zend_Registry::get('log')->debug('hello world');
```

It's not horrible I guess.  It just seems kind of verbose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting from this [newsgroup entry](http://n4.nabble.com/How-to-make-a-global-Zend-Log-with-Zend-Application-Bootstrap-td663442.html#a663442):

```
class My_Helper_Logger extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
{
  function init()
  {
    $this->getActionController()->logger = $this->getActionController()
                                                  ->getInvokeArg('bootstrap')
                                                    ->getResource('logger');
  }
}
```

> to apply the helper all you have to do is to put in the init()
>   function of Michael's example this line:

```
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper(new My_Helper_Logger());
```

> and in every action of your controllers now you can access the logger
>   as $this->logger

There is a number of other suggestions, so check the link.

Comment: +1 for a solution allowing controller access to `$this->logger`.

Comment: After reading some of the newsgroup one of the downsides to this method is you are not able to log inside models, view helpers and/or resource plugins

Comment: You could inject it into the View or Model from the Controller though.

Answer (score 1):

well you could wrap it in a 'manager class':

```
class My_Log_Manager
{
  static $_instance = null;
  protected $_logInstance = null;

  public static function getInstance(){}
  public function getLogInstance(){}
  public static function log($level, $msg)
  {
     self::getInstance()->_logInstance->$level($msg);
  }
}
```

you could then set up the static methods however you want either with something like catchall example, or by implementing `__call` or whatever. then you could jsut call the static methods on that class like `My_Log_Manager::<methodName>()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try skipping `addWriter()` to remove a single line:

```
$writer = new Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../app.log');  
$logger = new Zend_Log($writer);  
Zend_Registry::set('log', $logger);
```